# Some problems with gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: debian, gnome

I recently did a `apt-get autoremove` and ran into problems with my **gnome-tweak-tool.** It got uninstalled from my system. Later when I installed it again I wasn't able to get it up running unless I was root. So, I purged it again and reinstalled it fresh. Still the problem was not solved. After a lot of tinkering I was finally able to launch it after I did a `apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions.`

However the problem now is that I get the following message when I run the tweak-tool from terminal

```
(gnome-tweak-tool:10114): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to set text from markup due to error parsing markup: 
Error on line 1 char 190: Element 'span' was closed, but the currently open element is 'alt'
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.nautilus.desktop (key computer-icon-visible)
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power (key lid-close-battery-action)
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power (key lid-close-ac-action)
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power (key lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor)
```

So is there any way to include these missing keys. Or, do I have to do something else to solve this problem.

Also, why did autoremove uninstall my tweak-tool. From what i got to know it was supposed to remove dependencies that were no longer used.
I am using debian 8.

Comment: The messages are purely informative (`INFO`). Those keys no longer exist and you can't set them. Lid-close events configuration was moved to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

Comment: @don_crissti So these messages mean nothing important with respect to the working of the system. There won't be any problems?

Comment: No, they're harmless. You can safely ignore them (I get them too...).

Comment: Thanks @don_crissti  for your assurance :) I was kind of stuck up and uneasy about this for quite some time.

Comment: @don_crissti just to clarify, will the problem and solution be different if it was the init daemon instead of the systemd daemon.

Comment: Errh... you mean old `sysv` init ? No idea... but you're seeing those messages due to the fact that lid switch event configuration was removed from gsettings/gnome...  See if you can find anything useful [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=731602). HTH.

Comment: @don_crissti That was helpful :) If you could post what you commented as an answer, I shall close this question. Also, could you explain why autoremove had uninstalled my gnome-tweak-tool.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't as I'm not familiar with debian.